# What is the neutral and the male word for 'Hausfrau'?

Tags: word-usage, gender, gender-neutrality

I think the male word is Hausmann. But what is the overall, neutral word?

Comment: https://books.google.de/books?id=GQWO9vM0-vQC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=Hausmann+hausfrau+neutral&source=bl&ots=pWUl9mdDpE&sig=uylFn6kc3D3qhVnDSY7_Hpe_nys&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtq7iVoIDLAhUBnBQKHR6oDW0Q6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=Hausmann%20hausfrau%20neutral&f=false

Comment: @mle hast du schon im Link nachgesehen? Wie ich bereits schrieb: Hausmann ist das männliche Pendant zu Hausfrau. Wonach ich frage ist aber ein Wort, dass im Sexus neutral ist. Und zwar wird das Wort Neutral auch erwähnt, jedoch überhaupt nicht in dem Zusammenhang, sondern im Zusammenhang mit temporale Präpositionen. Im Buch geht es um Grammatik. Hausfrau/mann werden nur in Zusammenhang mit Genus, Sexus, Nomen und Nachsilben erwähnt. Meine Frage war nach einem neutralen Begriff.

Comment: _Das Heimchen_ :-)

Comment: Es gibt im Deutschen keinen geschlechtsunspezifischen Begriff wie etwa das englishe _homemaker_. Es bleiben also nur _Hausfrau und -mann_.

Comment: @Ingmar so ein Mist :/ ... Wie wäre es mit den Zuhausegehenden? Oder könnt ihr nicht ein tolles Wort erfinden? :D

Comment: Queere Freunde von mir sagen "Hausmensch". Das ist neutral.

Comment: Die offizielle Berufsbezeichnung lautet "Hauswirtschaftsfachkraft". Geschraubt, aber neutral.

Comment: @tofro das beschreibt eine _fach_kraft. Inwieweit es als passend für Laien zu gebrauchen ist, ist mindexstens diskussionswürdig.

Comment: @Amabile Scientius, bezüglich "Zuhausegehenden". Ein Hausmann bleibt zuhause und geht nicht arbeitend, daher würde ich sagen, dass "gehend" nicht passt. Es ist eher ein  "Zuhausebleibender" (das wiederum klingt aber eher nach Couchpotato)

Comment: @Burki das war nicht als Antwort gedacht,  sondern als Anmerkung,  dass auch die "professionelle " Welt hier offensichtlich ein Problem mit der Nomenklatur hat und auf geschraubte Begriffe zurückgreifen muss ' :)

Comment: Hausfrau ist kein Beruf, wie auch Schüler und Student keiner sind, obwohl man das einträgt, wenn ein Formular sonst nichts anbietet. Es sind quasi Erklärungen, wieso man keinen Beruf im Formular einträgt. Die soziale Rolle der Hausfrau kann auch ein Mann übernehmen, und so wie eine Frau beim Militär Hauptmann werden kann oder zivil Bürgermeister, so kann ein Mann auch die Haufrauenrolle übernehmen und ist dann Hausfrau. Dass das als irgendwie falsch empfunden wird liegt an mangelnder Kenntnis über das Geschlecht i.d. Sprache und an Konservativismus.

Comment: _Hausmann_ ist [nicht so neu oder selten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(Hausfrau%2BHausfrauen)%2C(Hausmann%2BHausmänner)%2CHausleute%2CHausfrau+und+Mutter%2BHausfrauen+und+Mütter%2CHaushälter%2BHaushälterin%2BHaushälterinnen&year_start=1748&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) wie manche denken mögen.

Comment: @userunknown Begriffe wandeln sich immer erst, wenn es eine reale Notwendigkeit gibt. Die ersten Frauen, die in Stadträten saßen, wurden auch noch mit Ratsherrr betitelt, bis die Leute geneigt waren, auch Ratsfrau zu sagen.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff: Und die Schüler? Die Briten? Die Geizigen?

Comment: @userunknown Was meinst du? Das sind sog. "generische"  Maskulina. Die Wörter sind zwar vom Genus her männlich, beschreiben aber nicht zwingend männliche Subjekte. Bei Wörtern die auf *-mann* oder *-herr* enden kann man das aber nicht sagen.

Comment: Doch, kann man.

Comment: @Chrissov: Die ersten 10 Treffer für "Hausmann", die ich Deinen Quellen folgend finde, sind sämtlich Personen mit dem Namen "Hausmann".

Comment: "Das Hausweib" ist, sprachlich, neutral. Wer der Religion des Gendersprechs anhängt muss das, wenn er konsequent ist, als neutral akzeptieren, denn "das" ist ja neutral.

Comment: Alle Kommentare und Antworten zu dieser Frage wurden auf deutsch geschrieben. Können wir die Frage übersetzen, damit es wieder paßt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Begriff "Hausfrau" hat mit Geschichte zu tun und kommt von dem, dass früher die Männer einer Arbeit mit Einkommen nachgegangen sind und Frauen mehr für den Haushalt und der Familienarbeit (Kinder etc.) da waren.
Wie du schon richtig gesagt hast, ist das männliche Wort dafür Hausmann, wird aber nach wie vor selten genutzt. Eine neutrale Form von "Hausfrau" bzw. "Hausmann" gibt es in diesem Sinn nicht.

Comment: Das stimmt auch nur für eine kurze Epoche und auch in dieser nur für eine kleine Mittelschicht. In Handwerksbetrieben und in der Landwirtschaft haben Frauen eigentlich immer mitgearbeitet. In proletarischen Milieus hat das Einkommen auch selten gereicht, um die Frau vom Broterwerb freizustellen. Nur in Beamten- und Angestelltenverhältnissen hat sich dieses Ideal realisiert, ist dann aber in den Medien (Romane, Filme) so zum dominierenden Ideal geworden, dass es heute ein falsches Bild der Vergangenheit prägt.

Comment: Der Begriff Hausmann hat aber auch einen Bedeutungswandel erlebt. Früher verstand man unter dem *Hausmann* den *Hausherrn*, also denjenigen, dem Grund und Haus gehörten und der das Sagen hatte. Der hat sich aber wohl eher selten um den Haushalt gekümmert. Überlebt hat diese Bedeutung u.A. im Begriff Hausmannskost (siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausmannskost)

Comment: @Janek Bevendorff, also ich glaube dieses Wort eine Bedeutungsverschlechterung erlebt, oder?

Comment: Warum Verschlechterung? Man versteht heute halt eher etwas anderes darunter als früher. Warum auch nicht? Für den Hausherren gibt es ja immer noch genug gehobene Begriffe.

Comment: @Janek Bevendorff, wenn du von einer Bedeutungswandel redest,es waere schön,diesen Bedeutungswandel festzustellen.

Answer (score 1):

*Hausfrau* ist – neben etwa *Putzfrau*, *Krankenschwester* und *Hebamme* – einer der seltenen Fälle, in denen eine Tätigkeit mit einem eindeutig weiblichen Lexem bezeichnet wird, die (heute) auch in signifikantem Maße von Männern ausgeübt wird. 
Der Begriff hat seine heutige Bedeutung, die eine entgeltliche berufliche Tätigkeit und sogar eine betriebliche Mitarbeit vor Ort weitgehend ausschließt, erst mit der Arbeitsteilung im Zuge der Industrialisierung im 19. Jahrhundert angenommen.

Da vom Weiblichen ins Männliche im Allgemeinen keine Form der Movierung – d.h. Geschlechtsbestimmung auf Morphemebene wie *Hausherr* → *Hausherrin* – etabliert ist, muss entweder die feminine Bezeichnung generisch verwendet werden oder eine Geschlechtsbestimmung auf Wortebene stattfinden, d.h. entweder *er ist Hausfrau* oder *er ist Hausmann*. Ersteres wird am ehesten bewusst gerade wegen des semantischen Bruchs gesagt.

***Hausmann*** wird heutzutage tatsächlich als Pendant zu *Hausfrau* gebraucht – und nur dafür. Der Begriff wurde früher allerdings auch in anderen Bedeutungen verwendet, laut DWB je nach Zeit und Ort als ‚Haushaltsvorstand, Hausvater‘, ‚Bauer‘ (im Gegensatz zu *Hofmann* ‚Ritter‘), ‚Mieter‘ und ‚Hauswart, Hausmeister‘, nach Adelung auch für ‚Hausherr‘ oder (im krassen Gegensatz dazu) fürs ‚Hausgesinde‘. Darauf aufbauend kommt *Hausmann* (in diversen Schreibvarianten) auch als Familienname vor.

Für viele der alten Bedeutungen findet sich im Plural gelegentlich auch ***Hausleute***. 
Generell bilden *Mann* und *Frau* zusammen den geschlechtsneutralen Plural *Leute*, z.B. *Kaufmann, Kauffrau, Kaufleute*, aber für *Hausfrau* und *Hausmann* im modernen Sinne hat sich *Hausleute* (noch) nicht eingebürgert. 
Das mag auch daran liegen, dass es in einem Haushalt entweder einen Hausmann oder eine Hausfrau oder weder noch gibt, aber nicht beide. 
Es gibt auch keinen Grund für einen Gemeinschaftsbegriff wie beim *Ehepaar*, das aus den *Eheleuten*, also *Ehefrau* und *Ehemann*, besteht.

Im Singular sind wirklich geschlechtsneutrale Begriffe selten.
Meistens gibt es entweder ein Lexempaar wie oben (*-mann/-frau, -vater/-mutter, -bruder/-schwester*) oder ein pseudogenerisches Maskulinum, das sowohl für männliche wie für unbekannte oder gemischte Extensionen verwendet wird und aus dem das Femininum per Derivation (Motion/Movierung) gebildet wird, üblicherweise mit *+in*.

Formal lassen sich selbst echt generische Maskulina movieren, auch wenn es unlogisch, unnötig oder unüblich ist, bspw. *?Menschin, ?Gästin, ?Hiwine*. 
Etwas eingeschränkt gilt das selbst für gebundene Ableitungsmorpheme wie *+ling* oder *+bold*, bspw. *?Lehrlingin, ?Raufboldin*. 
Für generische Feminina – das sind neben *Person* hauptsächlich abgeleitete Abstrakta auf *+kraft, +keit, +heit, +ung* etc. – gilt das hingegen nicht und generische Neutra zur Personenbezeichnung sind selten bzw. nicht für den allgemeinen Fall zu gebrauchen (bspw. *Weib, Opfer, Kind*, Diminutive wie *Mädchen*).

Die Komposita ***?Hausmensch*** oder ***?Hausperson*** lassen sich natürlich trotzdem bilden, können aber auch anders interpretiert werden, da sie nicht entsprechend konventionalisiert sind.

Vielleicht wäre angebracht, den Begriff komplett zu überdenken, statt eine einfache Ersetzung durchzuführen – wie bei diversen Pflegeberufen. 
Ich weiß nicht, zu welchen Ergebnissen so ein Prozess führen würde, vielleicht ***?Familienpfleger/-in***. 
Solche Bestrebungen gibt es meines Wissens aber bisher nicht oder zumindest nicht mit hinreichendem gesellschaftlichen Erfolg. 
Der Grund dafür mag sein, dass aus Reihen der Emanzipation eher eine Abschaffung der „Versorgerehe“ als eine Geschlechterangleichung angestrebt wird, d.h. das Ziel sind weniger Hausfrauen, aber nicht unbedingt mehr Hausmänner.

Answer (score -1):

Dem Trend folgend, dass Berufsbezeichnungen mehr über die ausgeübten Tätigkeiten definiert werden (siehe Studierende statt Studenten), würde ich **Haushaltende** bzw. **haushaltende Person** vorschlagen.

Das ist angelehnt an

> "Krankenschwester" -> "Krankenpfleger/Krankenpflegerin/Krankenpflegende" und
>
> "Hebamme" -> "Geburtshelfer/Geburtshelferin/Geburtshelfende".

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haushalten) ist "haushalten" übrigens

> 1. sparsam wirtschaften; mit etwas sparsam, haushälterisch umgehen
> 2. (veraltet) einen Haushalt führen

Mit Wiederbelebung der alten Bedeutung von "haushalten" wäre ein solches Konstrukt also möglich. Es ist aber bisher im deutschen Sprachgebrauch nicht existent (Googlen zeigt quasi keine Ergebnisse in diesem Kontext)

---

Following the trend to name jobs after the tasks ("Studierende" instead of "Studenten") I suggest **Haushaltende** (house keeper) or **haushaltende Person** (Person who does housekeeping).

This works somehow like

> "Krankenschwester" -> "Krankenpfleger/Krankenpflegerin/Krankenpflegende" (nurse)
>
> "Hebamme" -> "Geburtshelfer/Geburtshelferin/Geburtshelfende" (midwife)

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haushalten) says "haushalten" is

> 1. sparsam wirtschaften; mit etwas sparsam, haushälterisch umgehen (to be economical)
> 2. (veraltet) einen Haushalt führen ((old) to keep house)

so if we revive the old meaning of "haushalten" this construct would work. Nevertheless it is not used in German language until now (Google shows virtually no results with this meaning)

Answer (score -1):

Kurz aber treffend bezeichnet die

> Hausperson

sowohl Männer und Frauen als auch jedes sich jenseits dieser Kategorien definierende menschliche Wesen, dessen Tagesaufgabenkreis sich um die Besorgung des eigenen Haushalts dreht.

So wie es auch in Bildungskreisen, oder jedenfalls in Kreisen der Erwachsenenbildung, und ganz sicher aber jedenfall in Kreisen der österreichischen Erwachsenenbildung inzwischen üblich geworden ist, nicht mehr von *Lehrer* oder *Lehrerin* oder *Lehrkraft* zu sprechen, sondern typischerweise von einer

> Lehrperson.

Der Ausdruck mag im Deutschlanddeutsch noch nicht vollumfänglich angekommen sein, aber er ist auf dem Vormarsch.

Comment: Womöglich unabsichtlich illustriert der martialische Ausdruck des Vormarsches ganz gut den aggressiven und gleichgeschalteten Impetus. +1